# Custom field in option values in Sylius not visible

Tags: symfony, sylius

Using Sylius 1.10, I managed to add a new field in options and it was visible.

But now, I want to add custom field in option values.
But I'm not able to show the new field in values list: there is no template for option values, only the line `{{ form_row(form.values) }}`, in `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/views/ProductOption/_form.html.twig` that creates automatically the following

```
<div class="required field">
<div data-form-type="collection" id="sylius_product_option_values" class=" controls collection-widget" ...>
```

in which all translations are visible, and the code field, but my custom field. ;(

How can I find the rendering of this, to add my custom field?
Do I really need to explose the `{{ form_row(form.values) }}` line, generating the "code" field, my field and using foreach on translations?

Or I did something wrong? (This could be the right answer ;))

```
php bin/console debug:container app.form.extension.type.product_option_value
```

gives me

```
Information for Service "app.form.extension.type.product_option_value"
======================================================================

 ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       app.form.extension.type.product_option_value
  Class            App\Form\Extension\ProductOptionValueTypeExtension
  Tags             form.type_extension (extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductOptionValueType)
                   form.type_extension
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
 ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 ! [NOTE] The "app.form.extension.type.product_option_value" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the
 !        container was compiled.
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your issue correctly.
You've added a new field via form extesion but it's not showing in your .twig ? 

Have you overriden `form.html.twig` ? 
If you add a new field it won't show unless you override the template since sylius use `'render_rest': false` in it's template

Comment: You understood well ;). But the issue is how to override the form.html.twig in the case of values to be shown in options. 
Currently, there are all languages and codes displayed, and I don't know where I can find it...

Answer (score 1):

The correct template to overwrite is

> Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/views/Form/theme.html.twig

in this block you should add your custom field

```
{% block sylius_product_option_value_widget %}
<div class="ui segment">
    {{ form_row(form.code) }}
    {{ form_row(form.your_custom_field) }}
    <div class="five fields">
        {% for locale, translationForm in form.translations %}
        {{ form_row(translationForm.value, {'label': locale|sylius_locale_name}) }}
        {% if 0 == loop.index % 5 %}
    </div>
    <div class="five fields">
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope that's will be working for you.

Comment: I knew something like this were somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it. It works fine now!